# Change color of Pygame Surface

Tags: python, pygame

I've made a Rectangle class:

```
class Rectangle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, len, x, y, color):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.image = pygame.Surface((len, len), flags=pygame.SRCALPHA)
    # self.image.set_colorkey(Constants.WHITE)
    self.image.fill(color)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = (x + len / 2, y + len / 2)
    self.is_blocked = False
    self.x_pos = x
    self.y_pos = y
    self.x = math.floor((x - Constants.PADTOPBOTTOM) / Constants.CELL_SIZE)
    self.y = math.floor((y - Constants.PADLEFTRIGHT) / Constants.CELL_SIZE)

def update(self):
    if self.is_blocked:
       print("is update working?") # it is working. 
       self.image.fill(Constants.GREEN)
```

And when update() is called I want to change the color of the rectangle to green but it doesn't work.
I'm new to pygame and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Are you sure you set `is_blocked` to `True` before?

Comment: @sloth yes, I get the "is update working" message on console

Comment: @Rabbid76 the color is still white, I can't make the rectangle green

Comment: @Rabbid76 before the loop, just once, and in the loop I call all_spirtes.update(). all_sprites is a list with all my rectangles.

Comment: Are you sure that a) `Constants.GREEN` is actually green an b) you're not drawing another sprite on top of the one that should change the color?

Comment: @sloth yes, I'm pretty sure of both. If any of you guys want to take a look here is the code: https://github.com/andreipetrut99/PathVis
I want to change the color of a rectangle when i click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you keep creating new sprites every frame, so when you change the color of one `Rectangle` to green, it will be covered by a white one.

You do this by calling the `fill` function (which creates new `Rectangle` instances) inside the `drawGrid` function.

Comment: This solved my issue. Thank you so much! Idk how I put that line there.